# ExtJS Replace Gridpanel Store

Tags: json, extjs, grid, store

Is there anyway to remotely override/replace a GridPanel's store?

I have a grid that has a dummy store as I get an error if I don't declare as store:

```
this.ds is undefined
```

When my form is submitted, it makes a GET REST call & loads a JSON store with the results. I want this store to be the store of my grid and show it underneath the formPanel.
I can get it to show & return JSON but can't seem to replace the store.

I tried using
searchGrid.store = formStore //the JSONStore returned from form submit

**EDIT**
This if the data store:

```
var formStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
        url: '...',
        method: 'GET'
    }),
    root: 'Report',
    fields:[
            ....]
});
```

This is the loading / changing of the store:

```
var data = this.getForm().getValues();

        formStore.load({
            params: {
                fields: Ext.encode(data)
            }
        });

        var grid = Ext.getCmp('search');

        Ext.apply(grid, {store: formStore});
        grid.show();
```

Comment: Which version of Ext are you on?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
myGridPanel.getStore().proxy.setApi({read: url});
myGridPanel.getStore().load();
```

I'm using this solution when I want to read data from another url

Answer (score 1):

```
grid.reconfigure(store, colModel);
```

Works fine for me. Is the `formStore.data` compatible with Grid's columns configuration? You don't need to specify the column model in the `reconfigure` call if it didn't change.

Show a slice of your `formStore.data` and grid configuration.

Comment: I tried reconfiguring it with just the store specified but it didn't work showing an e is undefined error. The columns in the store match with the grid.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Ext.apply()?

From the [api](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext-method-apply):

> apply( Object object, Object config, Object defaults ) : Object

EDIT:

Here's how you use it:

```
Ext.apply(myGrid, { store : mystore }); //no need for the third parameter, but if you do want a default, then you can use one
```

Comment: I tried using it like Ext.apply(searchGrid, formStore, store); but it just returned the original store for the grid.

Comment: Ext.apply is of ho help here. Your code fragment is equivalent to a simple property assignment `myGrid.store = mystore`. Ext.apply is a rather simple helper function with very limited purpose (e.g. assigning a large number of properties and merge them with default values)

Comment: That still isn't working. I've edited the above question to show my store and how it is loaded. I'm not sure if maybe that is what's causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Should the root is inside reader? Like this

```
var formStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
        url: '...',
        method: 'GET'
    }),
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'Report'
    },
    fields:[
            ....]
});
```

Comment: that doesn't make a difference

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by moving the jsonStore to the grid itself and make it a singleton. Then reference to it from the form using StoreMgr